# Shared auth only works when running fullyParallel

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I am writing some tests using playwright and attempting to share auth state across the tests. I've [read the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#avoid-authentication-in-some-tests) and my setup is nearly identical to the first example.

Below I have pasted the relevant snippets. As you can see it's very basic/minimal, yet when I run the tests **not** as `fullyParallel` (or is `workers.length < test length`) the shared logged-in-state fails on the second test.

In this example (last snippet), the `Homepage` test works as intended and is logged into the app, but the second test, `Info page` is *not* logged in. When I set `fullyParallel` to `true`, both tests work/pass as intended.

Can anyone share any insight as to why we need `fullyParallel` to be enabled in order to have shared logged-in-state for serial run tests to take advantage of this state. I imagine there's some lack of knowledge on my part around browser contexts or something.

I plan on having `fullyParallel: true` at a certain point, but while building I like to keep the test files running in serial mode.

*auth.setup.js*

```
import { test as setup, expect } from "@playwright/test";
const username = process.env.USER_NAME;
const password = process.env.PASSWORD;

setup("Log into the web app", async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("https://www.example.com/");
    await page
        .getByRole("textbox", {
            name: /email address/i,
        })
        .fill(username);
    await page
        .getByRole("button", {
            name: /continue/i,
        })
        .click();
    await page.getByLabel("Password").fill(password);
    await page
        .getByRole("button", {
            name: /continue/i,
        })
        .click();
    await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/example.com/);
    await page.context().storageState({ path: "playwright/.auth/user.json" });
});
```

*playwright.config.js*

```
export default defineConfig({
    // ...
    fullyParallel: !!process.env.CI,
    // ...
    projects: [
        {
            name: "setup",
            testMatch: /.*\.setup\.js/,
        },
        {
            name: "chromium",
        use: {
            ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
            baseURL: "https://example.com",
            storageState: "playwright/.auth/user.json",
        },
        dependencies: ["setup"],
    ],
    // ...
});
```

*example.spec.js*

```
test.describe("Website", () => {
    test("Homepage", async ({ page }) => {
        await test.step("See homepage fields", async () => {
            await page.goto("/");
            await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/homepage/i);
        });
    });

    test("Info page", async ({ page }) => {
        await test.step("See users", async () => {
            await page.goto("/info");
            await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/info/i);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the actual error msg?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal there isn't an error message, the logged-in state is simply not shared so the second test times out.